# jQuery Training Videos

Tags: jquery

I want to learn as much about jQuery that I can. I learn very fast through video, are there any great jQuery training video resources out there on the subject?

I know about showmedo.com, which is a great resource but would like to know about others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/

They have some very good stuff.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a Lynda.com class 4 hours that might be useful too.  See http://www.lynda.com/home/DisplayCourseN.aspx?lpk2=48370 for more.